# Live-action '80s-'90s movie involving two factions of people who fought one another in mech-type suits

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, post-apocalyptic, mecha

This is going to be a long shot, but the only things I have to go by are that it's a post-apocalyptic film between '80s-'90s which was rented on VHS often.

The two factions of people fought one another in mech-type suits; think the cartoon *Exosquad*, but live-action. Is this real or did I imagine it?

- I swear it had the name Texas Rangers in the title... not 2020 Texas gladiators

Comment: "Robot Jox" maybe?

Comment: No not robot jox, robot wars, or crash and burn. Smaller body suit style mechs.

Answer (score 6):

That could be [*Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future). It was a live action tv series where the heroes had exo squad style power armor they used to fight machines bent on "digitizing" (some kind of painful upload process) all humans. It was post apocalyptic in that the machines had won the "metal wars", and captain power and his squad were insurgents fighting on a ruined earth. The enemy faction consisted of a winged robot with a beak, a tank-like robot, infinite robot grunts, and a human who betrayed earth for a leadership position in the robot faction. It was also available on VHS, probably because it had a light gun game that worked with the tv series, so they wanted people to not have to wait for it to air when they wanted to play.

Comment: No I have some captain power episodes on tape its more power rangers-esque than this movie was. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like **Gunhed** (1989)

It's a post-apocalyptic film where scavengers fight the robotic forces of Kyron-5, an AI thought to be destroyed that tried to wipe humanity off the Earth in 2030. The scavengers find an injured Texas Air Ranger on Kyron-5's island and come into the possession of Texmexium, a powerful energy source that Kyron-5 wants to use to wipe out all of humanity once and for all.

Complete with Bio-Droids, the titular GUNHED suits, and the Aerobot (controlled by Kyron-5).

Comment: I thought it could be this movie but have yet to find a way to watch it.

Comment: The DVDs are $100; VHS is $60; BR is $80 used on E-Bay.

Comment: Or, if you don't mind a grainy VHS transfer:
https://archive.org/details/video.guru20200327223921241

Comment: Gonna check out that link then suck it up and snag the tape off of ebay